# Смена кодировки при экспорте MySQL в CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно экспортировать из БД в csv файл,делаю через функцию fputcsv()
Сам код

```
    $result = $db->AllStudents($db);
$file_name = 'export.csv';

$out = fopen($file_name, 'w');

foreach ($result as $student){
    fputcsv($out,$student);
}
fclose($out);
```

Но при экспорте сбивается кодировка...
Сама БД в UTF-8
Но Excel открывает так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как изменить кодировку.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Это тоже UTF8. Так что при импорте данных в Excel укажите правильно используемую кодировку. А если Вы желаете получить свой CSV в другой кодировке - то сперва хотя бы узнайте, какая именно нужна... PS. Данные в CSV можно копировать запросом `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`, не гоняя их напрасно от сервера на клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что CSV действительно в UTF8, но так как это текстовый формат без метаданных, Excel открывает его как есть и читает в системной кодировке. В вашем случае похоже на попытку представить UTF8 в виде CP1251.

Попробуйте проделать следующий трюк:

1. Записать все как обычно
2. Взять получившийся файл и перегнать из UTF-8 в CP-1251 через [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/mb-convert-encoding)
3. Открыть через Excel получившийся файл

То есть примерно вот так вот:

```
$result = $db->AllStudents($db);
$file_name = 'export.csv';

$out = fopen($file_name, 'w');

foreach ($result as $student){
    fputcsv($out,$student);
}
fclose($out);
```

Далее после записи файла в UTF-8 сразу открываем этот же файл и перегоняем из UTF8 в CP1251 (это мое предположение, уточните вашу системную кодировку по умолчанию):

```
$csv_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
$csv_text_converted = mb_convert_encoding($csv_text, "CP1251", "UTF-8");
if ($csv_text_converted) {
    file_put_contents($file_name, $csv_text_converted);
}
```

После этого открываем тот же файл через Excel и смотрим, что получилось

Это не самое лучшее решение, хранить данные в UTF-8 - это нормально, современно и безопасно. Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону генерации Excel-документов в формате самого Excel средствами PHP (там довольно все просто), например сюда: HabraHabr про [PHPExcel](https://habrahabr.ru/post/245233/) / репозиторий на GitHub [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)